# Subdomain in python-Flask

Tags: python, flask, subdomain

I want to use subdomain in class. By that I nee to define SERVER_NAME in config, and this where the problem happen.
I have in my config:

```
SERVER_NAME = "domain.com"
```

but when I put only a domain.com, it works but if I put www.domain.com it not working any more. SO could I have a list of SERVER_NAME ( I have tried to change SERVER_NAME to a list but it fail)

Comment: What do you mean by "it not working" ?

Comment: it give the error " The requested URL was not found on the server. "